# pytest not working with PySide

Tags: python, pyside, pytest

pytest seems to be ignoring tests that use PySide.
For example, I have a file test_pyside.py with the contents

```
from PySide import QtGui

def test_dialog():
    dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    assert False
```

The output for running python -m pytest test_pyside.py is:

> ============================ test session starts ============================ 
>   platform win32 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0 rootdir: C:\Users\erik, inifile:
>   collected 1 items

That's it. No Error report. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test segfaults because it creates a `QDialog` without creating a `QApplication`. I suggest using the [pytest-qt](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/) plugin to take care of that for you.